# BASH - echo issues, wont print anything but while read argument

Tags: bash, echo

We are having a wierd issue.

We have this lines :

```
while read line2; do 
echo $line2 
done < $1 | `echo grep '.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*'` | sort -nbsk1 | cut -d "|" -f1 | uniq -d
```

Which prints what they should print. but, when changing the echo to ->

```
while read line2; do
echo "Hello World" 
done < $1 | `echo grep '.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*'` | sort -nbsk1 | cut -d "|" -f1 | uniq -d
```

It wont print anything, same result for anything different then $line2. 
Whats even more wierd is :

```
echo " $line2 Hello"
```

Will print the `line2` variable

```
echo "Hello $line2"
```

Print nothing

I have tried the same with `printf`, same results.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: I suggest you write less obfuscated shell scripts. You seem to be trying out complicated no-ops. Anyway, `"Hello World"` doesn't match the grep pattern, so clearly no output will be produced.

Comment: Hello World shouldnt match the grep pattern, it is the print inside the while read loop.. :\

Comment: The while read loop is getting piped through grep.

Comment: rici is right, to have your `read` _after_ the `grep` & more , run `done < <(some more complicate script here...)`.

Comment: I'm a bit new to the language, can you please explain me why the inside should match the grep pattern ?

Comment: You have DOS line endings (`\r\n`) in the input file.

Comment: What they are saying is that the commands are split by the pipes. You have `command1 | command2 | command3 | ...`, where your 'command1' is `while read line2; do echo "Hello World" done < $1` and your command 2 is `echo grep '.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*'`, your 'command3' is the `sort` and so on. Therefore, whatever comes out of your while will be piped to the other commands, whereas what you want is the opposite: to use everything after your "done" as the input for your while. That's why  Wrikken suggested that you group it with parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've written is equivalent to the following shell code:

```
cat $1 |
while read line2; do 
    echo $line2 
done |
`echo grep '.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*'` |
sort -nbsk1 |
cut -d "|" -f1 |
uniq -d
```

The `while read` loop takes the contents of file `$1` and echoes them, which does nothing other than remove leading and trailing spaces and replace internal spaces with a single space.  If you replace the `echo $line2` line with `echo "Hello World"`, that string is clearly not going to match the grep command that the output of the loop is being passed through, so producing no output is unsurprising.

When you change the `echo` line to `echo " $line2 Hello"`, you tack "Hello" onto the end of the input line, which then matches the `grep` command and gets sliced off the end of the string with the `cut` command, so it makes sense that it would have essentially no ultimate effect.

If you change the `echo` line to `echo "Hello $line2"`, any number at the beginning of the line becomes invisible to the `sort -ns`, which makes your `sort` call essentially a no-op.  This is probably why you're not seeing anything in this situation, although you probably would see something if two identical lines appeared in the input one after the other.  (In my testing on my machine, I see one such line because I happen to have two identical lines in succession in my test case.)

It's not exactly clear what you're trying to do since the `while` loop is almost a no-op.  It's possible what you want to do is something more like this:

```
grep '.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*' < $1 |
sort -nbsk1 |
cut -d "|" -f1 |
uniq -d |
while read line2; do 
    echo $line2 
done
```

... but I'm only speculating at this point.

Comment: Uhm, I'm trying to do all that pipes to get a "sorted input" and then read that input line by line using a while loop.
Your explain is great, really gave me alot of extras, I'll try to implement it as soon as I wake up.!